# How to log in hibernate which part of the code caused a given SQL

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

We can turn on all of the SQL related logging with the following settings in spring:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

If we have a standalone hibernate/springdata command like

```
myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
OR
enityManager.persist(myEntity);
```

then it is easy to debug what happened just by reading the generated SQL from the log.

But, how would you debug when there isn't any explicit ORM action like here:

```
@Transactional
void doHundredOfTask(Long id){
 MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(id);
 // here comes ton of action on the entity like settings field,setting/adding to collection
 // myEntity.setField1().. 
 //myEntity.setField2()
 //   ....
 // myEntity.setField_N()
 // myEntity.getSomeList.get(0).setSomeField()
 // no ORM action
}
```

At the end we don't explicitly save anything but after the transaction hibernate will flush the changes, hence a massive amount of SQL will occur in the log. If you have a ton of action on the entity and on it's associations then it is extremly hard to debug why a given SQL was triggered.

Is there a way to assign the generated SQL to the triggering code in the log?

edit: Right know all I can do is splitting up the code to smaller chunks / or commenting out some part of it. But this process is slow..

Answer (score 1):

[p6spy](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html) can print a stacktrace for each executed SQL statement. Here is configuration to enable this: `stacktrace=true`.

How to configure **p6spy** for maven project:

0. Add p6spy dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
  <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Wrap the jdbc connection with p6spy:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:p6spy:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver
```

2. Add *spy.properties* config src/main/resources/spy.properties

```
stacktrace=true
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.Slf4JLogger
logMessageFormat=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.MultiLineFormat
```

3. You can remove the properties bellow:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

With this configuration, p6spy will output SQL and the stacktrace. E.g.:

```
select x0_.id as id1_7_ from X x0_
15:10:16.166 default [main] INFO  c.p.e.spy.appender.Slf4JLogger[logException]-39 - 
java.lang.Exception: null
    at com.p6spy.engine.common.P6LogQuery.doLog(P6LogQuery.java:126)
...
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2094)
...
    at com.springapp.Test.test(Test.java:36)
...
```